# How to set up a repository using git-ftp?

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

I'm a newbie so please explain how to set up a repository?
I installed git-ftp.
I tried : `git ftp init -u my_User-p my_Pass - ftp://host.example.com/public_html`

but I got this error message :

> fatal : Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   fatal : Not a Git project? Existing ....

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsaS5.png)

Comment: Have you solved this? If any of the aswers solved your problem, please, mark it as the correct answer (checkmark bellow the question score).

Comment: you need to run `git init` in your repo, then tell git to start tracking files. `git ftp init` wont do anything unless its run from a git repo

Answer (score 15):

You have to setup a git repositor first:

Enter your Project directory:

```
cd my/Project/
```

Init a git repository on it:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Configure you FTP:

```
git config git-ftp.user demouser
git config git-ftp.url ftp.example.com/demofolder
git config git-ftp.password demopassword
```

Init the git-ftp client:

```
git ftp init
```

Push your changes to FTP:

```
git ftp push
```

Make your changes and commit:

```
git add someFile.html
git commit -m "Added someFile.html"
```

Push your changes again and only what have changed is pushed:

```
git ftp push
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a ftp git tool which is much easier to use: [Ftp-Git](http://redino.net/ftp-git/). It's a GUI ftp deployment tool which can push changed files in git repository to your ftp server. (All in a GUI way)

Answer (score 1):

To establish git FTP push Please follow the steps.

1. First Install GIT in window  i.e. https://gitforwindows.org/
2. After doing this, run Git bash as Administrator and write the following command.

   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp > /bin/git-ftp
   chmod 755 /bin/git-ftp
3. After this add these commands on cmd

   a) `git config git-ftp.url "ftp://ftp.domain.com:21"`

   b) `git config git-ftp.user "user@domain.com"`

   c) `git config git-ftp.password "YourPassword"`

   d) `git ftp catchup`

Please keep in mind if you have same code on Git and on Cpanel then Use this command

> git ftp catchup

If your Code is not same then simply run below command

> git ftp push

Comment: This worked for me. FTP is a bit slow, especially for uploading thousands of files. I'd recommend uploading a zip and extracting on the server for initial commits, then use `git FTP push` often with this slow speed in mind, it's not so bad for smaller commits.

Comment: Yes. Its very usefull for daily bases activites. Like if you worked on 100 files , you just push on git and simply run git ftp push command. And they will also present on Cpanel. Its pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not init a local git repository, into which this remote is supposed to be added?

Does your local directory have a .git folder?

Try `git init`

Comment: I followed the tutorial from this website http://anantgarg.com/2013/09/25/git-ftp-for-windows/ and finally it worked, but i can I pull/push/commit now ?

Comment: I believe initially you have not used the git ftp init. Good that it works now. Also Im no clear on your question.

Comment: my question is now using an IDE (e.g sublime text) how can i commit/push/pull data ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on [macOS](https://eastwest.se/apps/gitftpdeploy), take a look a GitFTP-Deploy.

(Disclaimer: I am the creator of this app. Developed it for satisfying my own itch)