# Jenkins Failure, git: 'ftp' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, macos, jenkins, deployment, git-ftp

I am using `Jenkins` to upload a git repo to my server via `ftp` and when I try to build the task it gives me this consistent error:

`git: 'ftp' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

I have installed `git` and `git-ftp` with brew in a macos high sierra. For some reason I haven't been able to find out why the `git ftp` command is not executing.

Comment: Print the PATH and see if git-ftp is present

Comment: This is the current path /usr/local/bin/git-ftp

Comment: when you run it locally does it work fine ?? if so..then do an `echo PATH ` and see what is different when you do an `echo PATH` from jenkins ... and add the missing env variables...that should definitely work

Comment: I did many untracked changes on httpd.conf and a bunch of installs that probably messed up my apache server. I had to reinstall everything to factory settings, I hope this time it works.

Comment: This question is bit similer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398565/how-to-set-up-a-repository-using-git-ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398565/how-to-set-up-a-repository-using-git-ftp) Probably the working directory ($PWD) should have the .git file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full ftp-git path instead of the short command like this :

`/usr/local/bin/git-ftp push --user USERNAME --passwd PASSWORD ftp://abc.com`

If you want to be nicer you can just add a symbolic link to main /usr/bin like this :

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/git-ftp /usr/bin/`

Basically, Jenkins could not recognize the main path of git-ftp so you have to clearly writing it in the command.

Good luck